# I get an error AXAPTA_Daily_Check' object has no attribute 'cnf'

Tags: python

I keep getting the error:

`AXAPTA_Daily_Check object has no attribute cnf;`

Here is my code:

```py
class AXAPTA_Daily_Check:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize Global Variable...
        self.OutputPath=Output_Path
        self.OutFile=''
        self.Data_Table= '''
                            <table align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="4" style="background-color:#397798">
                                        AXAPTA DAILY CHECK FOR DYNAMICS AX
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Check Environment</th>
                                    <th>Check Name</th>
                                    <th>Check Result</th>
                                    <th>Check Status</th>
                                </tr>
                         '''
        self.Check1=0
        self.Check2=0
        self.Check3=0

        # Reading Config File...
        try:
            with open (os.path.join(Script_Path,'AXAPTA.conf'), 'r') as f:
                self.cnf=json.load(f)
        except Exception as e :
            logging.error("Error: {}".format(str(e)))
        self.File_Name_Creation()
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

In these lines of your code:

> ```
> with open (os.path.join(Script_Path,'AXAPTA.conf'), 'r') as f:
>     self.cnf=json.load(f)
> ```

you assign `json.load(f)` to `self.cnf` which attribute you've not defined it before in your `AXAPTA_Daily_Check` object and you should define `self.cnf` in your `__init__` method of your `AXAPTA_Daily_Check` class.